# What does 1,45c1,45 mean in diff?

Tags: diff

I ran the following diff command:

```
diff out2.txt ourOutput2.txt
```

and got this as the output:

```
1,29c1,29
```

When I run:

```
diff -iw out2.txt ourOutput2.txt
```

There are no problems. The problem seems to be whitespace but I can't see any white spaces differences and tkdiff isn't highlighting any whitespace in blue either.

What's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe running `xxd` or `od -x` on both files will give you the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the output states that lines 1-29 are changed between the first and second files.  I would run `hexdump -C` on each file and compare the output.  Without more info, I would suspect that there is trailing whitespace or different line endings CR-LF vs LF.

Here are a few things to check:

1. are the file sizes different?
2. does `diff -w` show differences?
3. does `diff --strip-trailing-cr` show differences?

Comment: The hex outputs are very different. I'm just going to leave it.  It's for an exercise for university. If there's a problem I'll tell the professor he should run the tests with diff -w.
Also: 1 - yes. file sizes are different. 2 - no. 3 - no.

Answer (score 0):

If `diff` is having trouble, yet there are no visible differences, try using `diff -b` instead, which in effect collapses all white-space other than newline characters into a single space, and any white-space at the end of the line (before the newline character) is ignored.

If you actually wish to find the cause, you will want `cmp -l`. Carriage returns (CR) will be output as 15 and line feeds (LF) will be 12. This will signify an issue with line endings, and the entire file will compare differently as a result. Pipe the output of `cmp -l` to `head -n 1` because the rest of the output will be useless in this case.

If this doesn't happen, you will probably want to look for 11 (tab) and 40 (space) on the same line (if "out2.txt" is sample output, it probably uses spaces while "ourOutput2.txt" uses tabs or vice-versa). `grep` can help filter such lines using `cmp -l "out2.txt" "ourOutput2.txt" | grep '.[[:space:]]*11' | grep '.[[:space:]]*40'`.

Barring that, hex dumps of each file would reveal more information.